# Crossdomain JSONP with text file and hard-coded callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, file, callback, jsonp

I know it is popular problem and people solves it by writing a proxy on the server side. But I want to avoid it, I have a file with hard-coded callback `jsonResponse()`:

```
jsonpResponse({"keys": ["0", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"], "promoted": [3, 10, 44, 47, 47, 31], "upcoming": [187, 14, 285, 366, 322, 225]});
```

and I want to get it from another domain with `JQuery.ajax()`:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: URL + filename, 
  dataType: "text jsonp",
  jsonpCallback: "jsonpResponse",
  success: function(data) {
    // wrapping data
  }
});
```

and I get an error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://first.domain/filename.jsonp. 
Origin http://second.domain is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Is there any way to do what I want that way? Do I really have to use a proxy? If it's true, than why?

Comment: I believe you have to set [`crossDomain: true`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) in the `$.ajax()` options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're miscalling `$.ajax`.

You need to pass `dataType: "jsonp"`; it doesn't support multiple values.

Note that since you're using a fixed callback, you will not be able to make multiple concurrent requests, or they'll steal each-other's callbacks.

Comment: Calling `text` on the `dataType` seems a bit redundant as well.

Comment: Thanks! It gives me warning `Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/plain.` so I was shure that i have to use `text jsonp` to convert it like an xml in the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax. You mean multiple concurrent requests from a single browser, right?

Comment: @ciembor: That means that the server needs to send `text/javascript` but isn't.  JSONP only works through `<script>` tags, which contain script.

Comment: I mean from a single JS context (browser frame).

Comment: It works even with this warning, so I don't know if there is need of correcting it. If it is... I think it should be possible with .htaccess (but I'm not shure).